# What exactly should I backup in a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, backups, public-html, home-directory

I just uploaded my multisite WordPress site and I wanted to know what exactly should I backup from my Cpanel?

Someone told me just backing up wp-content and your databases should be enough. Is that true?

I have a complete backup of my home directory and my public_html folder and as long as I'm not making any changes in system (like upgrading wordpress core) what should I backup?

I'm sure I don't need a full backup when I just publish new articles or a new blog gets created in my multisite.

Comment: After doing a backup, think about testing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wp-content and your databases is almost enough.  I would also include wp-config.php

But take note that sometimes just restoring everything doesn't always work.  It should, I can't explain why it doesn't.  But sometimes things go wrong.

You could also consider one of the backup plugins, but whatever your solution, be sure to get your backups offsite.  Don't leave them on the server, keep them on your home PC or something like drop box.  If your user account disappears and your backups are on the server, you may as well have never done them.

**[UPDATE]**  When doing a backup and don't plan to do a restore in the near future, it might be a good idea to back up your entire WP install.  For example if you are on the current version 4.6.1 and there is a major upgrade to say version 5.0, that includes a database change, then your restore may not work on the new WP version.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I get a monthly backup of my whole web disk, a daily backup of my databases, and weekly backup of my public_html

Comment: The backups mentioned above plus htaccess is how I do it.

Comment: thanks for the update, I have full backups besides partial ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take wp-content, wp-config backup with your database, whenever you are doing a change in your website.

Comment: I think the same, But gotta make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my advice to you is:

**DON'T DO PARTIAL BACKUP!**

As web development in wordpress concerned, do backup of everything. Don't just backup one folder and database. There's also wp-content and wp-includes and few files outside thoose folders. wp-content directory has plugins and themes directory that you'd need to backup also.

Comment: I have a backup and a schedule to backup everything in one week and one month period, but since I have a multisite, I can't backup everything, everyday! (and I need too!). just looking for a way to minimize my traffic and always have latest backups.

Comment: I'm new here and my votes don't count yet.

Comment: What do you mean by that? :D